# Trigger event on first element matching a class in Capybara test

Tags: jquery, ruby, capybara

Is there any possible way to select first image from a list of images

```
< a class ="image">....</a>
< a class ="image">....</a>
< a class ="image">....</a>
```

while using the following code it shows the preview of all images.I only want to show the preview image of first one.

```
page.execute_script('$(".image").trigger("mouseenter")')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
page.execute_script('$(".image:first").trigger("mouseenter")')
```